# How do curves consist of points?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, intuition

According to Euclid, a point is something which has no dimensions. And we know that all curves of any type consists of points. Now this thing bothers me because if a point has no dimensions, i.e. in other words there is nothing, then how is it possible to draw any curve? 
The thing I could imagine is that maybe a point is not as Euclid thought. I mean a point can be thought of as a small line segment whose length is approaching zero but never becomes exactly zero. In this way, we can say that curves consist of points (the line segment with length approaching zero). But then it breaks the fact as given by Euclid that a point has no dimensions.  Please help me to get out of this dilemma.

Comment: You are wrong by thinking that the union of $n$-dimensional objects must be $n$-dimensional as well. Think of $\mathbb{R}^2$: It is the union of all lines $\mathbb{R}(x,0)$ which are parallel to the $y$-axis. These lines are all one-dimensional objects, but their union $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a 2-dimensional vector space.

Comment: No I think you didn't get my question . As we know point is fundamental. But point has no dimensions and so it cannot generate anything practically. So how then is it considered to be fundamental in the present Euclid 's definition-form

Comment: Ah okay, then I agree with the others: We live in 3-dimensional space, and however you "draw" something, it will in fact be 3-dimensional. The point is that "drawing" is hard to be defined/modeled in a mathematically correct way. you are merely moving a pen around space, and through some mechanism the ink is coming out and sticking on a sheet of paper after a certain period of time. So as soon as you want to imagine a (not really existing) pen that draws single points, it raises the question of how you even define that.

Comment: But it's not about defining "drawing" mathematically in a correct way. It is about the dilemma or something paradox that it comes into play whaen we compare two facts that point which is fundamental has no existence but still produces something taken in infinitely large number.

Comment: But isn't this the same as saying: How can the integral of a function over an interval $[a,b]$ have a positive value if the integral of the same function over ${a}$ (as a "interval with length 0") is zero? How can the probability that an (arbitrary) integer is even be 1/2 if the probability for an arbitrary integer to be 0 equals 0?
And I think your dilemma is also a similar problem as that the union of $n$-dimensional sets can build a $n+k$ dimensional vector space.

Comment: I think the point is: Just because the points are lines of length zero, it doesn't mean that they do not exist. The "length" is just a function assigning every line some value. Usually you probably define it such that it always takes non-negative values, but of course there may be objects with length 0, which Euclid defines as points.

Comment: @user306288 "But point has no dimensions and so it cannot generate anything practically." You have basically restated Zeno's paradox, and it's incorrect.

Comment: You cannot define all; thus, the "basics" can be elucidated in somw way, but it is hard to call these elucidation: *definitions*. In any case, Euclid's one "worked well" for many centuries. For useful elucidation, you can consider: (i) Dedekind: a point is a "cut" on the line, that "square" with modern axiomatic geometry: every two intersecting lines will meet in a point (in this way, we are left with the "undefined" *line* concept). 1/2

Comment: @jpmc26 : " You have basically restated Zeno's paradox, and it's incorrect" . Really !! It means the paradox has been resolved!

Comment: Or (ii) [Newton](https://books.google.it/books?id=sQ4SqrduTZoC&pg=PA19): "Thus in the Equation $x^2 =y$, if $y$ represents the Length of the Space at any time described, which (time) another Space $x$, by increasing with an uniform Celerity $\dot{x}$, measures and exhibits as described: Then $2\dot{x}x$ will represent the Celerity by which the space $y$, at the same moment of Time, proceeds to be described. And hence it is, that in what follows, *I consider Quantities as if they were generated by continual increase*, after the manner of a Space, which a Body or Thing in Motion describes."

Comment: @user306288 No, it means the "paradox" was based on faulty assumptions and/or understanding to begin with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Euclid did say that that "A point is that which has no part". It is nothing more that a whisper of an indication that "You are here." You can't really see a point since there is nothing there.

```
"...if point has no dimensions, i.e. in other words there is nothing,
 then how is it possible to draw any curve?"
```

If you're thinking in terms of "connecting the dots", it isn't physically possible. Pick a ridiculously small positive number, $\delta$. It doesn't matter how small. It is a fact that there are as many points in the interval $(0, \delta)$ as there are points in the universe. There is no way you can *physically* enumerate all of the points in the smallest of curves. I don't believe that Euclid had our understanding of infinity, but I think he was aware of its paradoxical abundance.

But you don't have to draw curves. They are just a set of points. A graph is just a representation of that set and only serves to fuel our intuition.

Euclid's definitions of point, line, and segments, have zero functionality. They may sound nice but they don't really say anything useful.

If you want to know what a point really is, propositions like the following are much more useful.

"Two distinct points determine a unique line."

"If two distinct lines intersect, then they intersect at a single point."

## addendum

Having reread your question for the upteenth time, it occurs to me that you may be thinking of infinitesimals. Infinitesimals are basically numbers that are smaller in magnitude than any real number but are not equal to zero. You may want to check out [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal) and [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis).

Comment: So what should I conclude from all of this ?

Comment: @user306288 - You should read about Zeno's Paradoxes.

Comment: I know about zeno paradox . So at the end I should conclude that what I asked is a paradox only?!!

Comment: @user306288 I think the point is that intuition is fine, but when it starts to get confusing (like in this case) stick to the rigorous (modern) definition of points and lines. Euclid's definition may be intuitive but is clearly not rigorous.. "A point is that which has no part", how are you supposed to work with that? What does part even mean? Is the null set a point then? And so on..

Comment: @user306288 - A line is not a physical thing. When you talk about the point with coordinate $(2,3)$, the point is the location, not what is at that location. When you talk about the line defined by $x+y=1$ you are talking about an infinite set of pairs of numbers that point at the graph and say "here, here, here, ...".

Comment: I can't help but point out ridiculously rediculously.

Comment: @user306288 - No, it's not a paradox. It seems to be a paradox because you're looking at it the wrong way and I can't get you to see it my way.

Comment: @user306288 - Have you ever checked out nonstandard analysis? I'm beginning to think it's what you are talking about.

Comment: @stevengregory : I haven't.  But I will check it out. But if you tell me about this , it would be a great help.

Comment: @stevengregory: I read the links. So without knowing I was talking about the infinitesimals :-) so now I want to know how can it be used to redefine a point? And what I thought about a point as a line segment approaching to zero (but not exactly zero like infintisimal) is correct?

Comment: @user, why exactly could you not be satisfied with leaving "point" as an undefined concept, and just working from how it relates to other geometric entities? Another thing, in the interest of rigor: "a point as a line segment approaching to zero" should probably be "what a line segment becomes as its **length** approaches zero". A geometric entity cannot become a number, but it can be certainly be represented by numbers.

Comment: @jm : I believe that mathematics is the only pure language in which we human beings can communicate with anyone and we cannot simply assume something correct as such unless and until a concrete proof ( logical and/or) mathematical)of the statement is not given. And of course we have to start from somewhere with some "basic" like Euclid did but it doesn't mean we can't scrutinize the "basic". And I am doing the same and that's why I couldn't be satisfied leaving point as an undefined cocept and just working from how it relates to other geometric entities. ;-)

Comment: @user306288 - My guess is that you will have to become an expert in nonstandard analysis first. You need to see that you want to redefine "space". That is not going to be easy.

Answer (score 13):

**Intuitive interpretation**:

A curve has an *infinity* of points. So many that the amount counteracts the abscence of dimensions, like an $0\times\infty$ undeterminacy.

More precisely, a curve still has no dimension transversally, but a finite (or infinite) dimension longitudinally.

You can think of it as the limit of a necklace of pearls (points of finite area) in contact, getting smaller and smaller but more and more numerous. In the end, an infinitely thin but continuous string remains.

Comment: IMO, your final paragraph is more important than the initial paragraph -- if you forget how points are related, then their union is always a zero dimensional discrete space, no matter how many.

Comment: @Hurkyl : I agree with you on this. How can 0*infinity counteract the absence of dimensions. It is undefined first of all. The second sentence does indeed make sense.

Comment: @Yves Daoust ,  Could you please explain, how to get a line segment out of a set of points. I am hopelessly stuck at understanding infinities.

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing theory with parctise.
A point does not exist in the real universe.
Anything you draw will have some dimensions.

Comment: But then how point could be defined?

Comment: I am shocked if point has no existence then what is its worth?

Comment: As you have already mentioned a line segment with length rending to 0. But this is within the realm of logic/maths and may not apply to the real world.

Comment: Well even straight lines or perfect circles do not exist in the real world. But we can use them to model real world curves/lines etc.

Comment: We know point is fundamental to every curve. And also curves like circle etc have not much usage but they have got their significance if we assume them consising of something and that something according to Euclid is point. Then if these curves or their deform shape have significance in daily life then why not point should be given the same kinda significance too?

Comment: @user306288 : Sorry I couldn't. understand what you meant.

Comment: I meant to say that you said that anything we draw has some dimension which in other words proves its existence but then the same is true for point.so it means point does not exist and so as every curve consists of point then we should get anything even collecting these points as point has no dimension which is a contradiction.

Comment: @user306288 : Look, mathematics is the brainchild of the human race. It takes inspiration from nature and we try to model nature as close as we can. If you were asked the same question : How do you define a point?, How do you reply.

Comment: Yeah I am completely agree with you .

Comment: "I am shocked if point has no existence then what is its worth?" Negative numbers have no existence, so what are they worth?

Comment: This is math.SE, we're not here to talk about the real universe ;)

Comment: Yeah, though sometimes it's good to have a look at the bigger picture, the place which inspired maths.

Answer (score 5):

A curve is completely determined by two facts:

- Knowledge of all of the points lying on the curve
- Knowledge that the curve is drawn on the Euclidean plane

When it's said that a curve is made out of points, one really means to include in the latter fact too, or something similar (e.g. a topology or a metric on the collection of points).

There are more sophisticated geometric techniques (e.g. tangent spaces, halos, germs, stalks) that probe the "infinitesimal" shape of the curve at the point;

For example, studying the tangent space to the curve would indeed allow you to say that, at each point where the curve is smooth, it consists of an infinitesimal line.

But just to reinforce my initial point, the shape of that infinitesimal line can be ascertained simply by knowing the curve is being drawn on the plane along with which 'nearby' points lie on the curve.

Answer (score 4):

A point in an n-dimensional Euclidean space is that point which consists of n coordinates which give a distinct location of that point.

A function in Euclidean space essentially provides a rule for defining a set coordinates in space for which that function is true.

You are correct in that the physical realization of a collection of 0-dimensional points is nonsense to create a physical 1-D curve, however, it makes tons of sense when you learn a bit more math in topics like set and measure theory

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing reality and the idealized world of maths. In an ideal world, a point has no dimensions. You could never actually *draw* a point. In reality, you can. You take a pencil, make a point on a piece of paper and say "that is the point". But the fact that you can see the point already means that is has some dimensions (the ink occupies a non-empty area in our real, three dimensional world). You have not actually drawn the point, but a *representation* of the (idealized) point.

Similar, if you *draw* a curve, you need to draw it with some thickness. This means you don't draw the actual *idealized* curve, but a real life *representation* of that curve.

Maths is founded in the real world, but goes one step further. Maths discovers the rules behind things, and abstracts them into an *idealized* world. This *ideal* world does not exist in *reality*, but it is nevertheless useful.

For example, *infinity* is a purely mathematical concept, yet it is tremendously *useful* for real-life applications, e.g. physics.

Comment: The question is not about curves and points in reality versus ideal curves and points. It is about how "ideal" points, which have zero dimension, can together form an "ideal" curve, which is not zero dimensional.

Comment: Which is precisely the same question?! Sorry, but if you have a curve, you have some term that all points that lie on the curve have to satisfy. There is nothing else a curve can consist of then the infinite amount of points that lie on it. You have to get rid of the notion grounded in reality that the curve actually is some object you can physically grab. Its not. You just map some numbers to others, and if you let the curve segment be infinitely small you asymptotically approach a point.

Comment: Not the same question at all. Even someone who perfectly understands that mathematical, "ideal" points and curves can't be "drawn" in reality, might have the same question about the relation between ideal points and ideal curves. That has *nothing* to do with the difference between physical reality and mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

As at least one other answer has mentioned, it takes an infinitude of points to make up a curve. (Or to make up any other interval, like the rather simple "curve" of the closed interval [0,1], for example.)

At least one other answer has also mentioned the notion of "measure," and that's probably the more appropriate way to think about the small-ness of a point: it's said to have "measure zero." If you've taken calculus, then you may recall that you can remove a finite number of points from the interval that you're integrating over, and it won't affect the value of the integral. Why? Because each point only has "measure zero," so its contribution to the total value of the integral is negligible, when compared to the infinitely-many contributions made by all the other points in the interval.

Don't forget, when you have a closed interval (or, once you get to topology-level stuff, a "compact" interval), those intervals will have infinitely-many points in them. Like take [0,1] again; there are infinitely many points in that interval. But cut it in half; say, to [0,1/2]. There's still infinitely many points in that interval. Cut it in half again, to [0,1/4]; still infinitely many points in that interval. You can keep cutting it in half as many times as you can imagine, and you'll still be looking at an interval with infinitely many points in there.

All this "infinitely many" stuff that you encounter in math; it may not seem to line up with the real world all that well, but it's necessary for doing calculus (because it's at the heart of the concept of continuity).

Answer (score 1):

This article by Prof. Lawrence Spector helped me a lot and I think it addresses exactly what your confusion is. I'm not sure what the policy is on just posting links, but I don't think i would do a great job paraphrasing what he wrote, so here goes: http://www.themathpage.com/aCalc/apoint.htm

I would also highly recommend reading on the same site: http://www.themathpage.com/areal/real-numbers.htm, about the historical evolution of the real numbers. I think it'll clear up a lot of the questions you probably already have or will have.

Comment: The commonly accepted policy here is to briefly summarize the relevant points of links, so that your answer is self-contained and useful even if the link goes down. But if you've no time to do that, it might be better to just leave a few comments instead of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some other answers have already mentioned the distinction between the ideal geometric world (which we can describe by mathematical rules) and the real world (which our ideal world is intended to approximate).

However, an interesting point is that Euclid never talked about **dimension** but merely [said](http://users.ntua.gr/dimour/euclid/book1/elements1.html):

> [Euclid Book 1 Def 1] σημειον εστιν ου μερος ουθεν
>
> [a] mark is that of which [there] [is] no part // A point is that which has no part.

It is amusing that we can force a set-theoretic interpretation onto this as:

> A point is a non-empty set with no proper subset. // A point is a singleton.

This coincides with the notion that two different straight lines that intersect do so at a point.

> If $A,B$ are distinct straight lines with an intersection, then $A \cap B$ is a point.

In more set-theoretic terms:

> If $A,B$ are distinct straight lines such that $A \cap B \ne \varnothing$, then $A \cap B$ is a singleton.

Nice? Furthermore, a line can then be said to be a union of points!